# Summation of trigonometric identities with the argument squared.

Tags: trigonometry, summation

Currently trying to solve the following summations:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sin(i^2)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \cos(i^2)$$

I know that the following summations have the solutions:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sin(i) = \frac{1}{2}(\sin(n) - \cot(\frac{1}{2})\cos(n)+\cot(\frac{1}{2}))$$

and,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \cos(i) = \frac{1}{2}(\cos(n) + \cot(\frac{1}{2})\sin(n)-1)$$

which were answered in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1043012/summation-of-trigonometric-functions-such-as-sin-x) post. No clue where to even begin.

Comment: I doubt there's a nice form for that. If you had $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \sin(2 \pi k^2/N)$ instead, you should be able to do it using Euler's formula and Gauss sums.

Comment: What make you think that a closed form exists?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net It is an assumption. I really don't know if a closed form exists.

Comment: You can get one sum basically in terms of the other, via $\cos{(k^2)} + i \sin{(k^2)} = e^{2 \pi i k^2}$, but that's on the page that you link to.

Comment: Are you ok with an approximation?  You should be able to get arbitrarily close if that's what you're after.